# Get All Result in Solr with Solrj

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I want to get all result with `solrj`, I add 10 document to `Solr`, I don't get any exception, but if I add more than 10 document to `Solr`I get exception. I search that, I get this exception for this, in ***http://localhost:8983/solr/browse*** 10 document in first page,11th document go to second page. How I can get all result?

```
String qry="*:*";
                CommonsHttpSolrServer server = new CommonsHttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");
      QueryResponse rsp=server.query(new SolrQuery(qry));
      SolrDocumentList docs=rsp.getResults();  
                        for(int i=0;i<docs.getNumFound();i++){

                            System.out.println(docs.get(i));                    
    }
```

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 10

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
    Integer start = 0;

    query.setStart(start);
    QueryResponse response = server.query(query);
    SolrDocumentList rs = response.getResults();
    long numFound = rs.getNumFound();
    int current = 0;
    while (current < numFound) {

        ListIterator<SolrDocument> iter = rs.listIterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            current++;

            System.out.println("************************************************************** " + current + "   " + numFound);
            SolrDocument doc = iter.next();
            Map<String, Collection<Object>> values = doc.getFieldValuesMap();

            Iterator<String> names = doc.getFieldNames().iterator();
            while (names.hasNext()) {
                String name = names.next();
                System.out.print(name);
                System.out.print(" = ");

                Collection<Object> vals = values.get(name);
                Iterator<Object> valsIter = vals.iterator();
                while (valsIter.hasNext()) {
                    Object obj = valsIter.next();
                    System.out.println(obj.toString());
                }
            }
        }
        query.setStart(current);
        response = server.query(query);
        rs = response.getResults();
         numFound = rs.getNumFound();


    }
}
```

Comment: Hello - Welcome to StackOverflow! It would be helpful to have some commentary along with answer so that it is easier to understand.

Answer (score 8):

An easier way:

```
CloudSolrServer server = new CloudSolrServer(solrZKServerUrl);
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery("*:*");
query.setRows(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
QueryResponse rsp;
rsp = server.query(query, METHOD.POST);
SolrDocumentList docs = rsp.getResults();
for (SolrDocument doc : docs) {
    Collection<String> fieldNames = doc.getFieldNames();
    for (String s: fieldNames) {
        System.out.println(doc.getFieldValue(s));
    }
}
```

Comment: Chen, try to add more details

Comment: CloudSolrServer is deprecated, use CloudSolrClient
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50350965/cloudsolrserver-in-solr-7-3

Answer (score 6):

numFound gives you the total number of results that matched the Query.

However, by default Solr will return only top 10 results which is controlled by parameter [rows](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#rows).
You are trying to iterate over numFound, However as the results returned are only 10 it fails.
You should use the rows parameter for Iteration.

For getting the next set of results, you would need to requery Solr with a different [start](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#start) parameter. This is to support pagination so that you don't have to pull all the results at one go which is a very heavy operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you refactor your code like this it will work

```
String qry="*:*";
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery("*:*");
query.setRows(Integer.MAX_VALUE); //Add me to avoid IndexOutOfBoundExc
CommonsHttpSolrServer server = new CommonsHttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");
QueryResponse rsp=server.query(query);
SolrDocumentList docs=rsp.getResults();  
for(int i=0;i<docs.getNumFound();i++){
    System.out.println(docs.get(i));
            }
```

The answer to why it's quite simple.

The response is telling you that there are *getNumFound()* matching documents, 
but if you do not specify in your query how many of them the response must carry, this limit is automatically setted to 10,

ending up
fetching only the *top 10 documents out of getNumFound() documents found*

For this reason the docs list will have just 10 elements and trying to do the get of the i-th elementh with i > 9 (Eg 10) will take you to a

*java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException*

just like you are experimenting.

P.S i suggest you to use the for iterator just like @Chen Sheng-Lun did.

P.P.S at first this drove me crazy too.