# CloudSolrServer in Solr 7.3

Tags: solr, solrj

I am new to Solr.

I want to build `CloudSolrServer`in Solr 7.3. However, I do not find `CloudSolrServer` in source code and API doc, but I do find `CloudSolrClient`.

Is `CloudSolrServer` deprecated? What's the new class name?

`import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.{CloudSolrClient(found), CloudSolrServer(cannot resolve symbol)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes [it is deprecated](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_3_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/CloudSolrServer.html), CloudSolrClient replaces it. It was just a better name, as this is the client to connect to Solr server.